# Transferring data from spreadsheet to a txt file, using a template language

Tags: python, excel

Within my organization we are working with two different software suits, that each model the entire energy system (heating, electricity, industry, traffic, etc.) for an entire country. These tools are used eg in universities to investigate "what happens if we put up so and so many wind turbines, and people drive less".

- Tool 1: [LEAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEAP%3aLong_range_Energy_Alternatives_Planning_System), good at defining long term targets, e.g. gradually shifting to electric cars, liniearly, from 2020 to 2040.
- Tool 2: [EnergyPLAN](http://www.energyplan.eu/), good at giving complete, hour by hour, data about one specific year.

We have put data in to LEAP. With the LEAP application, we can pick any year, eg 2020 and export all the data about that year into an xlsx file. We then want to take that data and create an input file for EnergyPLAN, which is basically a txt file in a very easy to understand format.

I am interested in any hints on how to solve this.

### Format of input file for EnergyPLAN

```
input_dh_ann_gr2=
11.735
input_dh_ann_gr3=
42.244
input_solar_ann_gr1=
0.023
```

I.e. Line 1 (and every other odd-numbered line) contains name of variable and an equals sign. Line 2 (and any even numbered line) contains the value of the above variable.

```
[variable_name]=
[value]
```

### Excel formula format:

Formulas in excel all begin with an equals sign followed by some expression. Data fields are referred to by the column-letter and row-number. E.g. A11. When there are several sheets (those small tabs that you see in the bottom) in an Excel file, you refer explicitly to the field, e.g. the field named "Energy Balance"

```
='Energy Balance 2'!B14
```

### My idea of a solution

I would like to write/define/use a template language to define the txt file. Maybe it could look as follows:

```
input_dh_ann_gr2=
{{ ='Energy Balance 2'!B14 }}
```

Sometimes the expressions are more complicated than just taking one field from the input file.

```
input_dh_ann_gr2=
{{ ='Energy Balance 2'!B14 + 'Energy Balance 2'!C14 * 1000 }}
```

As I see it there are two parts of the implementation:

1. Making a system that can parse a text file and extract the text from each placeholder. E.g. find every occurence of `{{ some expression }}`.
2. Making/finding a Python function that takes an xlsx file and an Excel expression, e.g. `='Energy Balance 2'!B14 + 'Energy Balance 2'!C14 * 1000`, and then returns the value of that expression. I hope that a Python library exists, that can do this.

What do you think of my idea. Is it doable? Is it a good/poor solution? All input is appreciated| :)

Comment: Can you save the xlsx into a csv? if so, I would forget the template engine, parse a csv with a python script and use regex to define the txt file. If total automation is the goal and there is no chance of an export to csv option from LEAP, you could automate the save to CSV in vba. let me know and I'll see if I can whip something up for you

Comment: I need some time to consider all the options, but I might get back to you. Thanks for your comment :)